# FFJSON semi-stream parsing

Tags: json, go

I'm newbie to Golang, and we have problem with JSON parsing.
We have structure like that:

```
{
 method : "get",
 endpoint : "users",
 data : {
   key1 : "val1",
   key2 : "val2",
   ... 
 }
}
```

And out data value can be very large, so default library produce a lot of garbage during parsing.
Our goal is to parse generic JSON, and send data to endpoint, so we don't need to parse it.
I can not find out how to do it correct in ffjson, how should by struct be described?

```
type struct Entity {
   Endpoint string
   Method string
   Data ???
}
```

Comment: [`*json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage)

Comment: @thwd would it parse json object, or string only?

Comment: It will treat the JSON value as an opaque slice of bytes i.e. not parse it.

Comment: @thwd looks like it does a job, thanks!